# How to apply a Kalman filter when the measurement equation is not in the form of $z_k=Hx_k+v_k$

Tags: kalman-filter

Given an observable $z,r$ and unobservable $x$, I have a process of the form:

$x_{k+1}=x_k+w_k$

$z_k=a_1 z_{k-1}+a_2 z_{k-2} - \frac{s}{2} (r_{k-1}-x_{k-1}+r_{k-2}-x_{k-2}) + v_k$

which in my understanding are transit and measurement equations.

I am a beginner in Kalman-filter. In all places I researched, the measurement equation is in the form of $z_k=Hx_k+v_k$, but how should I apply Kalman filter to the above system?

Comment: I assume that you mean that $z_k$ and $r_k$ are measurable? Namely "observable" has specific meaning in the context of a Kalman filter, namely it refers to [observability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observability).

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen here by 'observable' I mean I have data of $z_k$ and $r_k$ given any $k$.

Answer (score 0):

For the measurement equation, the general equation is 
$$z_k = h(x_k) + v_k$$
where $h()$ is a function. For the vector case, $h$ is replaced with an operator $H()$. For a linear measurement, $h$ is linear in $x_k$ ($H$ is hence a matrix multiplication). The optimal tracker is a Kalman one. For non-linear measurements, an Extended Kalman Filter is used to linearize $h$ in the neighborhood of $x_k$.

In your case, $h$ depends on previous measurements, since 
$$z_k- a_1 z_{k-1}-a_2 z_{k-2}  = - \frac{s}{2} (r_{k-1}+r_{k-2}-x_{k-1}-x_{k-2}) + v_k$$
that is
$$z_k(1- a_1 z^{-1} - a_2z^{-2})  = - \frac{s}{2} (r_{k}(z+z^2)-x_{k}(z+z^2)) + v_k$$
which is
$$z_k(1- a_1 z^{-1} - a_2z^{-2})  = - \frac{s}{2} (r_{k}-x_{k})(z+z^2) + v_k$$
This looks like an infinite impulse response. I'm not sure whether Kalman filters are of usage here.

Comment: To apply Kalman filter, is it a necessary condition for $z_k$ to be a function of $x_k$?

Answer (score 0):

In the equation $z_k=H\,x_k+v_k$ the $z_k$ refers to a vector containing all measurements, $x_k$ the entire state describing the entire dynamics and $v_k$ the measurement noise all at the $k$th time step. So your definition for $z_k$ and $x_k$ do not match these. Namely, the measurements should also contain $r_k$ and the entire state should contain all information such that future states can be obtained from it, which in your case should contain $z_k$, $r_k$ and $x_k$. It can be noted that since since the dynamics of $r_k$ is not specified one could also interpret them as an input to the system. Therefore, in order to write the system of the form

\begin{align}
\text{x}_k &= F\,\text{x}_{k-1} + B\,\text{u}_k + \text{w}_k \\
\text{z}_k &= H\,\text{x}_k + \text{v}_k
\end{align}

one can define the state as $\text{x}_k = \begin{bmatrix}x_k & x_{k-1} & z_k & z_{k-1} & r_{k-1}\end{bmatrix}^\top$, the input as $\text{u}_k = r_{k-1}$ and output as $\text{y}_k = z_k$ (the output of $r_k$ is already included in the input), such that

$$
F = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{s}{2} & \frac{s}{2} & a_1 & a_2 & -\frac{s}{2} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
-\frac{s}{2} \\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
H = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$

describe the same system dynamics as in your question. The corresponding process noise vector and observation noise can be written as

$$
\text{w}_k = 
\begin{bmatrix}
w_k \\
0 \\
v_k - \frac{s}{2} u_k \\
0 \\
u_k
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
\text{v}_k = t_k,
$$

where $u_k$ and $t_k$ are the noise of the measurements of $z_k$ and $r_k$ respectively. You did not specify that the measurements where noisy, which which case $u_k,t_k=0$.